# What kind of fly is this?

Tags: soil

I keep having small flies in my flowerpot soils and my plants. I think they already were in the package of soil I bought.

[image]

Any idea what kind of fly this is and what I can do about it? I'm suspecting it is the St. Mark's fly.

Answer (score 3):

They are fungus gnats or Sciarid flies. The adults are harmless but the larvae can damage cuttings and the roots of seedlings. They are more common in permanently wet compost. The RHS has more advice on them https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?PID=804

St. Mark's fly is bigger and hairier https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bibio_marci